# Accord.Video.FFMPEG stream display in Accord.Controls.VideoSourcePlayer

Tags: ffmpeg, aforge, accord.net

I am new in camera programming. For learning purpose I have download Accord-Framework C# source code.

Thus if we have JPG or MPEG Stream then we can easily display in Accord.Controls.VideoSourcePlayer.

But if we have FFMPEG Stream then how can we display in Accord.Controls.VideoSourcePlayer.

Please anyone can guide me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ok you need this Library **AForge.Video**

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AForge.Video/
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html

Import it to your project

```
using AForge.Video;// first of all

private MJPEGStream mjpegSource;  
// create video source add your url
mjpegSource = new MJPEGStream("http://localhost:8080");
// open it
OpenVideoSource(mjpegSource);
```

Comment: Please provide some additional discussion instead of just a code dump

Comment: @XCoder: That's not what Alex is suggesting. Their comment isn't a criticism of your code. The issue is that people coming to this question that don't know how to do this would benefit from further explanation of what each method does and why they're appropriate here. If you look around Stack Overflow, you'll find the highest voted and accepted answers—i.e., the ones deemed most useful by the community—often include some explanation as to _why_ the code works, not just a block of code showing _how_ to solve the problem. As you contribute to Stack Overflow, that's something worth striving for.